# Serial port - changing settings during usage

Tags: linux, serial

I am using one of Gumstix Overo boards, it has OMAP3 CPU, which includes some UARTs.

Now, I am wondering what will happen if I will be sending some data on some serial port (for example `/dev/ttyO0`), and during that time, I will use `stty` command to change port settings, for example speed?

Is it possible to do such thing or should I firstly, stop using serial port, change settings and then start using it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be some data loss in your case ,So It is advisable to stop using serial port then change serial port settings and start using it again.